# Cannot use CABasicAnimation with Mapbox iOS framework

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, cabasicanimation

I am trying to use `CABasicAnimation` or key frame animation on an `MGLAnnotation` but I couldn't find a way to do it since the `MGLAnnotation` doesn't call "addAnimation".
According to the old documentation it was possible using an `RMMarker` but this class doesn't exist in the new version.

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk-legacy/examples/simple-cabasicanimation/

I created the `CABasicAnimation` object like this:

```
let hover = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
hover.additive = true
hover.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointZero)
hover.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(0.0, -15.0))
hover.autoreverses = true
hover.duration = 1.0
hover.repeatCount = 500
hover.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
```

I can't add this animation to any possible class.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Mapbox iOS SDK v3.2.1, it is not easily possible to animate annotations. MGLAnnotation is rendered directly at the GL level and is not a subclass of UIView, which means that typical Core Animation techniques cannot be applied.

Enabling the use of native views (e.g., those based on UIView) as annotations is a planned feature for v3.3.0.